# Unbrick Kindle Touch

Tags: kindle-touch, unbricking

My KT stopped working all of a sudden and will no longer turn on. I have tried the holding down the power button trick numerous times and charged it for over 24 hours but there is still no response. I also tried using Kubrick but when I boot into it, the wizard doesn't start automatically and I can't figure out how to run it manually.

Sorry about the quality of screenshot but this is where kubrick stops.

[image: Screenshot]

Anybody have experience with this situation?

Comment: Do you get a charge indicator light when charging?

Comment: @JamesJenkins Yes but it seems to be a bit random as to which colour the light is. It's mostly  orange but has gone green and back to orange and sometimes no light, all on the same charge...

Comment: Can you specify how exactly the wizard does not start? Are there any error messages? Do you see something like `kubrick login:` or `root@kubrick:~#`?

Comment: Also a very simple workaround would be to try the live cd on another pc.

Comment: @Tim I don't have access to another PC at the moment unfortunately but I've added a screenshot of where the kubrick boot disk stops. Hitting tab displays a list of commands, some of which I've tried but nothing has happened.

Comment: @doovers This basically means that the livecd is not booted (its bootloader does not find something). I suggest we should try to troubleshoot in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ebooks.stackexchange.com) instead of discussing in the comments.

Comment: @Tim sounds good how do I start chat?

Comment: @doovers [I created a new room.]http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12754/kubrick-troubleshooting

Comment: @Tim I've tried a number of ways to get kubrick to work such as USB CD and finally parallels VM which was the only one that actually ran the wizard but despite the wizard running it hangs on the 'Putting device into fast boot mode' screen showing waiting for device... any ideas?

Comment: @Tim Managed to get one step passed that with a new cable but at the point where I'm prompted to make a selection on the screen, there is nothing but a blank display...

Comment: @doovers The readme explicitely states that you should `Make sure that you are performing steps 3 and 4 with physical hardware, i.e., on a real computer, and with a real CD/DVD or USB stick, not in a virtual machine!`, so do not use a VM. I do not really understand at which point you are. Has Kubrick already booted and is the wizard started?

Answer (score 2):

It may be that your battery has burst. That would be the most likely cause of an abrupt breakdown. If the device is no longer under warranty, I'd suggest opening it up (check for videos on YouTube) and having a look. Replacement batteries are easily obtainable and, if you can operate a screwdriver, putting one in is within any user's capability.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. One question though, if the battery was goosed, would the kindle show up intermittently as a USB device when plugged in to my laptop?

Comment: I don't know. But I speculate there is an intermediate state between "OK" and "complete failure" that might permit that.